# ¿Cómo hacer una ventana modal con CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, style

Necesitó construir una ventana modal, que se vea al estilo de una PopUp (Encima de la pagina es decir que sobre salga), y en ella tener un formulario.

Escribí algo de código, pero no obtengo el estilo deseado por que NO se ve delante de la pagina.

Mi código CSS

```
.awindow {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


.awindow-content {
    margin: 0% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color:dodgerblue;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
}

.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Mi código HTML

```
<div id="nuevaTarea" class="awindow" >
            <div class="awindow-content">

            <span class="close" onclick="OcultarNuevaTareaPopUp()">&times;</span>

            <label>Tarea</label>
            <input type="text" id="tarea" name="tarea" runat="server"/><br />

            <label>Tipo tarea</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tipoTarea" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

            <label>Estado Tarea</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="estadoTarea" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

            <label>Tipo Servicio</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tipoServicio" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

             <label>Tarea Valor</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tareaValor" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

            <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio"  runat="server"/><br />

            <label>Fecha Final</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal"  runat="server"/><br />
               
            <label>Descripcion</label>
            <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="3" cols="10"  runat="server"></textarea><br />

            <label>Tiempo Estimado</label>
            <input type="number" id="tiempoEstimado" name="tiempoEstimado"  runat="server" min="0.5" max="100000" step="0.5"/> <br />   
                
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Enviar" />

        </div>
    </div>
```

Quisiera quitar lo gris que esta a los lados y que el formulario resalte mas sobre la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te recomiendo eliminar el fondo oscuro, ya que es el que hace que el formulario resalte, en su lugar te recomiendo hacerlo que use el 100% del alto de la pantalla, y centrar el contenedor del formulario, algo como esto... (quite el display: none; para que puedas visualizar como quedaría).

```css
.awindow {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.awindow-content {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color:dodgerblue;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nuevaTarea" class="awindow" >
            <div class="awindow-content">

            <span class="close" onclick="OcultarNuevaTareaPopUp()">&times;</span>

            <label>Tarea</label>
            <input type="text" id="tarea" name="tarea" runat="server"/><br />

            <label>Tipo tarea</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tipoTarea" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

            <label>Estado Tarea</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="estadoTarea" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

            <label>Tipo Servicio</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tipoServicio" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

             <label>Tarea Valor</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="tareaValor" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />

            <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio"  runat="server"/><br />

            <label>Fecha Final</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal"  runat="server"/><br />
               
            <label>Descripcion</label>
            <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="3" cols="10"  runat="server"></textarea><br />

            <label>Tiempo Estimado</label>
            <input type="number" id="tiempoEstimado" name="tiempoEstimado"  runat="server" min="0.5" max="100000" step="0.5"/> <br />   
                
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Enviar" />

        </div>
    </div>
```